# Amplify makes `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()` error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, amplifyjs

I got this error with Amplify, I have already finished the build and run. It worked correclty until a few days ago and I didn't change any amplify settings after that.
But I suddenly got this error today.

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()
```

and

```
[ERROR] 35:34.138 DataStore - Sync processor retry error:
```

[image: screen shot]

Build and Deploy is succeeded.
It still doesn't make sense to me.
Could anyone provide insights into this matter or suggest potential solutions? Your assistance would be immensely appreciated.